# Mailto failing in React Native MobileIron environment

Tags: javascript, react-native, uri, mailto, mobileiron

Trying to send an email on-press using React Native's Linked API, but receiving an error describing an unhandled/unresolved promise rejection. App is deployed via MobileIron. I'm trying to open the default Mail app on iOS.

Made sure the passed in argument was the correct type and the correct formatting. Made sure Linking was working in general in the environment and that I could call other default apps (like phone for a phone call).

Last place left to look is at MobileIron itself and how it blocks/allows communication with other apps.

```
let email = random@random.com

Linking.openURL(`mailto:${email}`)
```

I'm expecting the above code to call the default email app on the phone, or preferably the specific MobileIron-approved email app, and populate the "To:" field with the passed-in email variable.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: Is mailto fail on simulator or device? because mailto does not work on ios simulator and some android virtual device

Comment: Good question - it's failing on both the iOS simulator and on an iOS device

Comment: Linking is a Promise. catch the error to see whats the problem.